# I'm using Git as a way to bookmark, and download awesome code. How can I organize this better?

Tags: git, github, code-organization

I have no idea how to use git, but it's awesome that I can download code and use them in my projects.

Problem is that I need to organize, categorize, and tag what this code is for, or else it all gets lost.

Is there a better way to organize projects like:

- Sample Code and Templates (read only)
- Projects with real intention to fork and commit to.
- Things to learn
- Projects for that future "side business" you've been thinking of

Comment: If it is on GitHub,, you can star them, bookmark them in your browser adding a description,, or fork them into your account. You could then rename the forks based on your classification above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple feature of Git which can probably cover most if not all of your requirements.  It is called *branching*, and it is a fairly lightweight and inexpensive way of maintaining multiple code versions of a project.

With branching, you could have one branch as a sandbox and another one for your real contributions.  And when it comes time to contribute back some of your own work, GitHub has a feature called a *pull request*, which is a way that one of your branches can be brought back into the remote master branch in the repository.